# productsRequest never called in app purchases swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am new to swift so I am creating a new app. I am trying to implement in app purchases in my application but the **productsRequest** method never called. I tried to follow all other stack overflow responses but nothing changed. Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.

This is my RemoveAdsManager.swift:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

public class RemoveAdsManager {

     class func removeAds(){
         let iap = IAPManager(productID: IAPManager.removeAdsID)
         iap.beginPurchase()
     }

     class func restoreRemoveAds(){
         let iap = IAPManager(productID: IAPManager.removeAdsID)
         iap.beginRestorePurchases()
     }

     class func areAdsRemoved() -> Bool{
         return UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "pro_version")
     }

     class func removeAdsSuccess(){
         UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "pro_version")
         UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
     }

     class func restoreRemoveAdsSuccess(){
         removeAdsSuccess()
     }

     class func removeAdsFailure(){

     }

     class func removeAdsDeferred(){

     }

 }
```

This is my IAPManager.swift:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit

public class IAPManager: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver{
    static let removeAdsID = "com.******.*****.******"

    let productID: String
    init(productID: String){
        self.productID = productID
    }

    public func beginPurchase(){
        if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments(){
            let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: [productID])
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
        else{
        }
    }

    public func beginRestorePurchases(){
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }

    public func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse){
        if let product = response.products.first{
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
        }
        else{
            RemoveAdsManager.removeAdsFailure()
        }
    }

    public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue){
        
        for transaction in queue.transactions{
            if transaction.transactionState == .restored{
                let productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier

                if(productID.lowercased() == IAPManager.removeAdsID.lowercased()){
                    RemoveAdsManager.restoreRemoveAdsSuccess()
                }

                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }

    public func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]){
        for transaction in transactions{
            let productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier

            switch transaction.transactionState{
            case .purchasing:
                break
            case .purchased:
                RemoveAdsManager.removeAdsSuccess()
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .restored:
                RemoveAdsManager.restoreRemoveAdsSuccess()
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .failed:
                RemoveAdsManager.removeAdsFailure()
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
            case .deferred:
                RemoveAdsManager.removeAdsDeferred()
                break
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And finally, this is the button where the user can press to buy the in app:

```
@IBAction func didTapBuy() {
        RemoveAdsManager.removeAds()
    }
```

Thank you so much for all of your help. I am trying to learn, so any response is welcome.

Comment: `let iap = IAPManager(productID: IAPManager.removeAdsID)` sounds odd.  It's kind of the retain cycle.

Comment: @ElTomato and do you know how can I change it?

Comment: Create a simple struct for products and their AppleIDs.  And get rid of RemoveAdsManager.  Instead, work with IAPManager through a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

`removeAds()` seems to calls `beginPurchase()` at this point you should call something like

```
let payment = SKMutablePayment(product: product)
SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
```